# VB .NET Check FTP account if already exist

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I try to create an application for Windows OS for can sync files from computer with a FTP account.

I need a function in Visual Basic for check if FTP account exist.

For example:

```
Public Function CheckAccountFTP(ByVal host As String, ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String) As Boolean
    '' Function Content ...
    ... Try/Catch with what ...
End Function
```

What I can use for this?

Comment: .NET Framework doesn't have a specific function for checking FTP account existence; otherwise the framework will be bloated with CheckRdpAccount, CheckSshAccount, CheckTelnetAccount, CheckSmptAccount, so on and so forth. Do you have idea how FTP makes connections? If you can guide me, I can figure out the code.

Comment: All you can do is try to connect and catch the exception if it fails.  You almost certainly won't be able to distinguish between an invalid user name and a valid user name with an invalid password though. Most systems aren't going to tell someone who is trying to hack into the system that they are halfway there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use this function:

```
Public Function CheckAccountFTP(ByVal sHost As String, ByVal sUser As String, ByVal sPassword As String) As Boolean
    Dim bStatus As Boolean
    Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(sHost), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(sUser, sPassword)
    Try
        Using request.GetResponse()
            bStatus = True
        End Using
    Catch
        bStatus = False
    End Try
    Return bStatus
End Function
```

And then it will be used:

```
    If CheckAccountFTP("ftp://localhost", "aninu", "123123123") = True Then
        '' OK ...
    Else
        '' Not OK ...
    End If
```

Comment: What's the point of such a function? Why don't you directly do your operation (sync files)?

Comment: In my application, I check if FTP account exist and then start to sync all files. This app, check file by file if exist on FTP account and if not exist or exist but is not last version of file, sync this (here I can add size limitation or a limitation for file extension and another things).

Comment: Your didn't answer my question. You have only repeated, what we already know from your question.